# How do I start a service based on a ServiceInfo object?

Tags: android, service

In my app, I query for the list of services that have a specific Category in their intent-filters. This goes just fine, I get back a List containing ResolveInfo objects. In these ResolveInfos I found the "serviceInfo" field, that's supposed to describe the details of a found service.

Now how do I construct an Intent from the serviceInfo, that can start the found service?

My code now is like this:

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction("<my custom action>");
  i.addCategory("<my custom category>");

  List<ResolveInfo> l = pm.queryIntentServices(i, 0);

  gatherAgentNum = l.size();

  if(gatherAgentNum > 0){
   for(ResolveInfo info : l){
    Intent i2 = new Intent(this, info.serviceInfo.getClass());
    i2.putExtra(BaseAgent.KEY_RESULT_RECEIVER, new GatherResult(mHandler));
    startService(i2);
   }
  }
```

This's obviously wrong, the "info.serviceInfo.getClass()" just returns the serviceInfo object's class. Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Edit: The solution (at least the one I used):

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("<my action>");
        i.addCategory("<my category>");

        List<ResolveInfo> l = pm.queryIntentServices(i, 0);

        if(l.size() > 0){
            for(ResolveInfo info : l){
                ServiceInfo servInfo = info.serviceInfo;
                ComponentName name = new ComponentName(servInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, servInfo.name);

                Intent i2 = new Intent();
                i2.setComponent(name);

                startService(i2);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at :

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#packageName
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html

I guess you could try to replace the getClass class with `.packageName` - and use `packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(String)`

Also take a look at:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html
- `queryIntentServices`, `resolveService`

Comment: Welcome. Always thankful if people post their solution in the end. Makes it easier for others too.